# PDO / HASH Registration form

Tags: php, pdo

I just made my first registration form with password confirmation, hashing with BCRYPT and PDO. As a beginner, looking around on StackExchange, I seem to miss a lot.

To keep it simple for myself, I coded PHP and HTML on the same page. Hence I'm just into PHP for 3 days now.

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cPassword = $_POST['cPassword'];

    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'loginform';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8mb4';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }


    if ($password != $cPassword)
        $msg = "Wachtwoord komt niet overeen!";

    else {

        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$name, $email, $hash]);

        $msg = "U bent geregistreerd!";
        header( "Refresh:3; url=/Login2/inloggen.php", true, 303);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very good code. Speaking of the things that are written in it, there is very little I would *change*. Only a few things are coming to my mind,

- I would move the database connection code into a separate file and then just include in other scripts that needed a database connection.
- Using the Refresh header is old fashioned, inconvenient and buggy. I would rather redirect a user to the newly created account page. So they would know that an account has been created at once.
- I wouldn't hardcode a particular hashing algorithm, and rather use PASSWORD_DEFAULT instead.

That's all. But of course some things could be *added* to this code as well. You can add some verifications, like as to see

- if the username is not empty or already exists
- whether the password is not strong enough
- whether email follows the proper format or already exists
- all other verifications you can think of

And for this purpose it is useful to make $msg not a string but an array of strings, to collect all possible errors in one variable. You can check this approach in my [recent answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/214895/101565)

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I think you covered some interesting things here and to be honest, It's exactly what I needed. At this moment I can use XSS scripts as username and that's something I really don't want. Thank you for reviewing my code, I've set some new goals to work on tonight. Appreciate it!